# Wrong App Store app version number from request http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting info dictionary from appStore by request http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=(identifier) for my app and receive 1.8.2, but in appStore version is 1.8.3, and if I setup app on iPhone - local info about app version is correct 1.8.3, why the wrong version number is coming from appStore request?

```
func isUpdateAvailable(completion: @escaping (Bool?, Error?) -> Void) throws ->  URLSessionDataTask {
guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
    let currentVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
    let identifier = info["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String,
    let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)") else {
        throw VersionError.invalidBundleInfo
}
print("currentVersion: \(currentVersion)")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    do {
        if let error = error { throw error }
        guard let data = data else { throw VersionError.invalidResponse }
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any]
        guard let result = (json?["results"] as? [Any])?.first as? [String: Any], let version = result["version"] as? String else {
            throw VersionError.invalidResponse
        }
        print("AppStore version: \(version)")
        completion(version != currentVersion, nil)
    } catch {
        completion(nil, error)
    }
}
task.resume()
return task
```

}

// To use it I'm call:

```
_ = try? isUpdateAvailable { (update, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else if let update = update {
        print(update)
    }
}
```

Comment: The incorrect version number of the current version of the application continues to be returned within 24 hours from the date of publication of the application, but what is the reason and how to get the correct version number?

Answer (score 3):

Use `https:` instead of `http:` for bundle ID. I noticed same thing even after App Store shows correct version. Something changed in last few months at apple version servers.